# When are indiscrete reflection groups Coxeter groups?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, coxeter-groups, reflection-groups

A well-known theorem of Coxeter states that any discrete group $W$ which is generated by reflections across (possibly affine) hyperplanes in Euclidean space is a *Coxeter group*: it has a presentation with generators $\{r_i, i \in I\}$ and relations $r_i^2=e, \forall i$ and $(r_ir_j)^{m_{ij}}=e$ for some numbers $m_{ij} \in \{2,3,\ldots\} \sqcup \{\infty\}$.

I am interested in when the discreteness hypothesis can be discarded. For example, take the simplest indiscrete case: let $W$ be generated by reflections across two central hyperplanes meeting at a $\pi$-irrational angle. Then $W$ is not discrete since it contains a dense set of rotations, but $W$ is still a Coxeter group with generators $\{r_1,r_2\}$ corresponding to the two given reflections and $m_{12}=\infty$.

Note that I do not require $W$ to be generated by finitely many reflections, nor my Coxeter groups to have $|I|$ finite. However I would still be interested to know about any results particular to the finite case.

Questions:

1. Is any such group $W$ a Coxeter group? I suspect not.
2. As a particular example: is the orthogonal group a Coxeter group? Again, probably not, but I don't see how to prove this.
3. Is there some nice condition, more general than discreteness, which guarantees that $W$ is a Coxeter group?

This [other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310809/examples-of-reflection-groups-that-are-not-coxeter-groups) also asks for reflection groups that aren't Coxeter groups, but without focusing on discreteness. It also doesn't insist on working in Euclidean space and does assume finite $|I|$. It got no answers.

Comment: @SamHopkins Is this different than my first sentence?

Comment: Ah sorry I see that now. I was just confused because you link to another question that asks for reflection groups which aren't Coxeter groups and say it doesn't focus on discreteness- but necessarily such groups must be indiscrete, right?

Comment: @SamHopkins that's right.

Comment: This paper discusses defining relations in classical groups: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869378901321. It suggests that Sigrid Becken established the defining relations for the orthogonal group, but that paper is in German so I can't understand it. But "All relations between reflections are consequences of relations whose length is at most four." is interesting...

Comment: Here is the paper of Sigrid Böge (née Becken): https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1962.210.205 which I believe would answer your question 2.

Comment: Even if I know a presentation for the group with the generating set of all reflections, it's still not obvious to me how I would decide if some subset of these form the simple generators for a Coxeter group presentation.

Comment: Fair! But it would be a first step.

Comment: O(3) does not even embed in a Coxeter group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Great. Can you say why or give a reference?

Comment: I will add details later on. The point is that $O(3)$ contains an isomorphic copy of a (uniform) irreducible higher rank lattice (a lattice in a product of several $SL(2,R)$'s)  and those do not embed in Coxeter groups.

Answer (score 2):

Over on math.SE, [I pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148054/) that there are three reflections $a$, $b$ and $c$ in $O(3)$ such that $\langle a, b \rangle$, $\langle a, c \rangle$ and $\langle b, c \rangle$ are infinite dihedral, but $(abc)^6 = 1$. However, I didn't actually prove that it wasn't a Coxeter group. Maybe this question will motivate someone to finish off the proof.